# Select values from two columns

Tags: excel

I need your help for excel (VBA not accepted). I have a table with customer data like:

```
customerId | billDate | price
10001       25.04.2019  100
10002       25.04.2019  100
10003       25.04.2019  100
10001       25.04.2019  100
10001       26.04.2019  100
```

now I want to display this on another sheet. no duplicates.
in SQL I would do it with `GROUP BY billDate`.

so I want do have a sum of the price for `customerId` 10001 grouped by the `billdate`.

on my sheet it should be:

```
customerId | billDate | price
10001       25.04.2019  200
10002       25.04.2019  100
10003       25.04.2019  100
10001       26.04.2019  100
```

I have tried all. nothing works. I tried with index and so on.

Comment: have you tried a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i think is pivot table. another solution is consolidate.

Sheet 1:

[image]

1. Import a helper column with the below formula as in the picture.

   ```
   =B2&"_"&C2
   ```
2. Select Sheet2.Range("A1")
3. Data - Data Tools - Consolidate

   Function= Sum

   Refernece=Press the arrow at the end of the box and select you data. 
   (Sheet1.range("A2:D6))

   Press Add

   Use lables in= Tick Left column
4. Press OK

Sheet 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @ScottCraner says, PivotTable is the way to go here. If you want to avoid that, you can also filter by unique values by using the `Sort & Filter` -> `Advanced` filtering option and selecting your `billdate` as your `List range`, checking the `Unique records only` and set your new sheets as the `Copy to` range.

Once you've done this, use a `=SUMIFS(X,Y,Z)`, where:
**X** = Range of your "price" columns, **Y** = Range of your original "billdate", and **Z** as your specific billdate